# How to re-translate a forecast I wrote in R run on a dataset I downloaded from Tableau back into a SCRIPT_REAL function in Tableau

Tags: r, forecasting, tableau, arima

I want to add a SARIMA forecast of the next two days onto each line in the following Tableau graph:
[image]

But Tableau only does Exponential Smoothing forecasts and if I create a moving average table calculation, then I can't add a forecast on to that, so I downloaded the data from this graph into Excel, cleaned it up a tiny bit, loaded it into R, then wrote the following code which works to create SARIMA forecasts (after converting that Excel file I created by clicking Worksheet+Export+Crosstab to Excel to a csv file named ts_flights):

```
ts_flights <- read.csv('Time-Series data on daily flights.csv')
ts_flights$Date <- as.Date(ts_flights$Date, 
                                    format = "%d/%m/%Y")

TS_flights <- ts(ts_flights[, 2:4], start = c(2022, 5), frequency = 7)

sarima_forecast <- function(ts_data) { sarima_model <- Arima(ts_data, 
                                                             order = c(1, 1, 1), 
                        seasonal = list(order = c(1, 1, 1), period = 7))
  sarima_forecast <- forecast(sarima_model, h = 2)
  return(sarima_forecast) }
```

All of the above creates a 2-day SARIMA forecast using the prior 7 days, so:

```
> sarima_forecast(ts_flights[,2])
    Point Forecast     Lo 80    Hi 80      Lo 95    Hi 95
316       16.42007  6.392889 26.44725   1.084821 31.75532
317       17.17526 -1.455819 35.80634 -11.318518 45.66904
> sarima_forecast(ts_flights[,3])
    Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
316       20.14386 16.65176 23.63597 14.80315 25.48458
317       20.48233 14.20151 26.76314 10.87665 30.08800
> sarima_forecast(ts_flights[,4])
    Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
316       60.34350 51.31253 69.37447 46.53183 74.15517
317       60.46693 43.95295 76.98090 35.21098 85.72287
```

But only after I had completed all of this in RStudio did I find out about the SCRIPT_REAL() function in Tableau where I could have tried to do all of this in Tableau from the start! So now I am trying to figure out how to replicate all of that within a SCRIPT_REAL() function in Tableau, this is what I have so far:

```
SCRIPT_REAL("library(forecast);
TS_flights <- ts(arg1, start = c(2022, 5), frequency = 7); 
sarima_forecast <- function(ts_data) { sarima_model <- Arima(ts_data, 
                                                             order = c(1, 1, 1), 
                        seasonal = list(order = c(1, 1, 1), period = 7))
  sarima_forecast <- forecast(sarima_model, h = 2);
", COUNT([Tail Number])
```

I just don't know what to put for the dataset name I called arg1 as a placeholder. What can I put as the name of the dataset here and am I on the right track besides that?